# django form create or edit exclude object

Tags: django, forms, object

I wonder how i could exclude  the editable object from a queryset, and it still works if i use the same form for creating an object.

My form:

```
class CountryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Form to create or edit Countries."""

    name = forms.CharField()
    flavor = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'width': 300, 'height': 100}))
    history = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'width': 300, 'height': 100}))
    likes_set = Country.objects.all().exclude(self)
    likes = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=likes_set, empty_label="Country it likes"

    class Meta:
        model = Country
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this in `__init__()` method, and also pass `instance` variable if available while instantiating the form.

```
class CountryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Form to create or edit Countries."""

    name = forms.CharField()
    flavor = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'width': 300, 'height': 100}))
    history = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'width': 300, 'height': 100}))
    likes = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all(), empty_label="Country it likes"

    class Meta:
        model = Country

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CountryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'instance' in kwargs:
            self.fields['likes'].queryset = Country.objects.exclude(kwargs['instance'])
```

In view you would have to create form as

```
myform = CountryForm(instance=country_obj)
```

or

```
myform = CountryForm(request.POST, instance=country_obj)
```

Comment: Thanks i go try this out and dive deeper into the __init__ never quite got that :(

Comment: I think i get the idea of this, the only thing i dont figure out yet is, how does this work on the create a new Country, should i just make an empty object and pass that along?

Comment: @HansdeJong, when you are creating new object, don't pass `instance` variable. In that case, `likes` will list all objects.